# Python smartest way to tranform a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

Lets assume we have a dataframe like this:

| Key | Type | Status | Parent | More Columns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Task1 | Task | Approved |  |  |
| Task2 | Subtask | Approved | Task1 |  |
| Task3 | Task | Approved |  |  |
| Task4 | Subtask | Approved | Task3 |  |
| Task5 | Subtask | Draft | Task3 |  |

What is the smartest way to get the following dataframe?

| Key | Type | Status | Parent | More Columns | Parent Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Task2 | Subtask | Approved | Task1 |  | Approved |
| Task4 | Subtask | Approved | Task3 |  | Approved |
| Task5 | Subtask | Draft | Task3 |  | Approved |

I tried the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

data=[['Task1','Task','Approved','',''],['Task2','Subtask','Approved','Task1',''],
      ['Task3','Task','Approved','',''],['Task4','Subtask','Approved','Task3',''],['Task5','Subtask','Draft','Task3','']]

df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Key','type','Status','Parent', 'more columns'])

df

df.loc[~ df["Parent"].isnull(), "Parent Status"] = 'Approved'

out = df.loc[~ df["Parent"].isnull()]

out
```

which results in:

| Key | Type | Status | Parent | More Columns | Parent Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Task1 | Task | Approved |  |  | Approved |
| Task2 | Subtask | Approved | Task1 |  | Approved |
| Task3 | Task | Approved |  |  | Approved |
| Task4 | Subtask | Approved | Task3 |  | Approved |
| Task5 | Subtask | Draft | Task3 |  | Approved |

Not bad, but not exactly what I need, if the status of a task with type task is different, e.g. in review, then this should also be reflected in the result.
Tasks with the type task can only be parents, so I wouldn't need them in the result, but the parent status is not always approved, and this should be reflected in the final dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a column is null with the [`pandas.Series.isnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isnull.html) method.

```
df.loc[~ df["Parent"].isnull(), "Parent Status"] = 'Approved'

out = df.loc[~ df["Parent"].isnull()]
```

If instead you have spaces instead of null values, you can do something analogous:

```
df.loc[df["Parent"] != '', "Parent Status"] = 'Approved'

out = df.loc[df["Parent"] != '']
```

Side note: it's not recommended to have space values inside a dataframe when the values are missing: blank spaces are treated as existing values and you won't be able to use pandas tools to address empty cells specifically.